# Trapping SIGTERM and restarting a script works exactly three times on macOS

Tags: linux, bash, macos, kill, sigterm

I have a setup of two bash scripts, one starting a node server (`start-server.sh`) and one that runs the first script and reruns it whenever it gets terminated via `SIGTERM` (`start.sh`).

`start.sh` looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap './start-server.sh' TERM
./start-server.sh
```

Inside of `start-server.sh`, some environment variables are exported and afterwards a `node` server is started.

To restart said server, I have the following bash snippet:

```bash
kill -TERM "-$(ps -ax -o pgid,command | tr -s " " | grep -E "[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+/bin/bash ./start.sh" | xargs | cut -d " " -f 1)"
```

which sends SIGTERM to the whole process group that got started by `start.sh`, causing all child processes to terminate and the `trap` inside of `start.sh` itself then restarts the `start-server.sh` script.

On my personal machine running `Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64` and `zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)` this works flawlessly.

**However on my colleagues machine, running macOS and zsh 5.9, repeatedly running above `kill` command stops working after exactly three times. How can that be?** After three restarts, `start.sh` itself just stops upon issuing a fourth `kill`. Even waiting a moderate amount of times between the `kill` executions does not change this.

---

*edit*:

We now discovered that the following works on both machines:

```bash
#!/bin/bash                                                             
                                                                        
START_SCRIPT_PATH="./start-server.sh"                                   
                                                                        
handle_sigterm() {                                                      
  echo "Received SIGTERM, will restart"                                 
}                                                                       
                                                                        
handle_sigint() {                                                       
  echo "Received SIGINT, will exit"                                     
  exit 1                                                                
}                                                                       
                                                                        
trap 'handle_sigterm' SIGTERM                                           
trap 'handle_sigint' SIGINT                                             
                                                                        
while true                                                              
do                                                                      
  bash "$START_SCRIPT_PATH"                                             
  sleep 1                                                               
done
```

I would still be interested in understanding why the first solution does not work on both machines, i.e., what exactly the difference is between these two. Is it a timing issue where the first solution can terminate when `start-server.sh` gets terminated, before the new run is started? Seem strange, as it repeatedly only stopped working after the third restart...
However, we tried executing with `bash start-server.sh` instead of `./start-server.sh` and also the other "signal styles". The difference seems very likely to be related to the loop.

Comment: I tried to make (1) and (2) more clear.

> (3) Maybe the difference is in the fact the first method allows `./start-server.sh` and its descendants to be started again before the previous instance exits, while the second method restarts `./start-server.sh` strictly after the previous instance exits.

I was under the assumption, that the signal would "bubble up" through the process group, i.e., `start.sh` as the "parent" (not sure what the exact term is here) would receive the signal lastly. Am I understanding your comment correctly, that this assumption is false?